# CSS - can you set a style rule for a child element of a particular class?

Tags: css, class

Is there a way of making css rules for child elements of classes?

ie if I have:

```
.special {
    font-size:15px;
}
```

Can I then have

```
.special p{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

so that when I do this:

```
<div class="special"><p>Hello There</p></div>
```

The "Hello There" will be both 15 point and in bold?

Comment: Why don't try it ?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. From the spec:

- [Descendant combinators](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators):

> The following selector:
>
> ```
> h1 em
> ```
>
> represents an `em` element being the descendant of an `h1`
>   element.

- [Child combinators](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators):

> The following selector represents a `p` element that is child of `body`:
>
> ```
> body > p
> ```
>
> The following example combines descendant combinators and child combinators.
>
> ```
> div ol>li p
> ```
>
> It represents a `p` element that is a descendant of an `li` element; the `li` element must be the child of an `ol` element; the `ol` element must be a descendant of a `div`. Notice that the optional white space around the "`>`" combinator has been left out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you are assigning style property to `parent` instead of `child tag` it get assigned to it automatically.

```
.special {
    font-size:15px;
}
.special p{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Even this works,

```
.special {
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

But it's good to assign style property to targeted element separately. It becomes easy to understand what property are assigned to `.special` and `p tag`.